# Dynamic call to an Instance Variable

Tags: python

I have a dynamic string based on the current file's extension called "extension"

```
fileextension = os.path.splitext(file.filename)[1]
extension = fileextension.replace(".","")
```

Lets say extension = "pdf"

How would I be able to call the Ext.pdf() instance variable below?

```
class Ext:
    def pdf(self):
        self.filetype = "pdf - Adobe Portable Document Format"
    def txt(self):
        self.filetype = "txt - ASCII text file"
Ext = Ext()
```

I have tried:

```
Ext.filetype = getattr(Ext, extension)()
```

But this comes up with a blank entry

Comment: I would avoid naming your variable exactly the same as your class (`Ext`).

Comment: Don't re-use the class name as the instance variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called the instance attribute correctly. To fix your issue do not assign the result to the `filetype` attribute:

```
ext = Ext()
getattr(ext, extension)()
print(ext.filetype)
```

It did not work because you return `None` within `pdf()` and `txt()` method and assigned that to `filetype` attribute.

Note that I relabeled the instance of `Ext` to `ext` since it may be not a good idea to override a class definition by an instance.